# WinSCP not showing all files in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, winscp

I am a learner to Hadoop environment and i am trying some example available in Internet. I observed that while copying files from Windows file system to IBM Cloud through WinSCP, there i observed some differences. Can someone help me what i am doing wrong here?
[image]

From the above picture you can observe that **MaxTempOutput** folder is displayed Cloud machine(Hadoop), but not in file system. Similarly the file "**mytest.txt**" displayed in Cloud machine is not displayed with hadoop list command.

Comment: I believe WinSCP connects to the local filesystem of the server. It doesn't show you the content of HDFS.

Comment: How are you connecting to Haddop? What protocol? Does any other client show the missing folder, when using the same protocol?